# html for where to call onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Never done html or any related projects before. Though as relatively straightforward  as it appears so far. I still need some of you wisdom. I'm making a form.

A html form has an attribute `onsubmit` to which I can assign a function for it to call.

```
<... id="formId" onsubmit="aFunction();" >
```

I can also get the onsubmit attribute via the `document.getElementById("formId").onsubmit` etc.

Is one method preferable to the other? And am I right in thinking the `getElementById` would override any functions assigned to be called in the HTML form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The later one is preferable (using `.onsubmit` in Javascript) since it modularizes your code. Modularization in the sence that it seperates the Javascript code from your HTML. So, your `.HTML` files will contain only HTML code and `.js` files will contain only Javascript code.

This way it is easy to  maintain the code of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that setting `onsubmit` will override other event handlers. The alternative is to use `addEventListener`, which will allow you to bind multiple event handlers to an event.

I think binding the event in JavaScript is the best way to go. Your HTML markup should be clean, without these kinds of logic in it. Of course this is a matter of opinion, but I'm pretty sure the balance is tilting to *this* opinion. :)

A quick note: IE8 doesn't support `addEventListener`, but you can use the similar `attachEvent` for that browser. For that and more information about `addEventListener`, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener